# Como centralizar o texto dentro do input type="time"?

Tags: html5, css3

```css
.menor {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input class="menor" type="time" id="abre" name="abre" required><br><br>
```

No computador, funciona normalmente. Mas no celular, o texto não fica alinhado dentro da caixa. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Sem querer te desanimar, mas existem estilos que são default do sistema e não do browser. Talvez no dispositivo mobile ele não aceite esse tipo de estilo, principalmente um input com tipo date, time, tel, etc...

Comment: @hugocsl fiz um teste no Galaxy A5 com width e padding-left e funcionou.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo bom de mais então, e com o text-align no centro deu certo? Para essa situação tente usar a medida em REM ou EM pq px pode dar problema se o cara aumentar a fonte pra 20px por exemplo ai vc perde a referencia do tamanho padrão

Comment: @hugocsl  text-align não. Mas há que ter bom senso não se pode colocar conteúdo maior que o espaço designado.

Comment: O bom é trabalhar com %, nesse caso. Obrigado, galera.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode configurá-lo no centro usando o padding-left do CSS.

Para ter efeito em todos os dispositivos configure uma largura e aplique um padding-left.

Para uma largura de 100px coloquei um padding-left de 22 px.

**CSS**

```
.menor{
    padding-left:22px;
    width: 100px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="menor" type="time" id="abre" name="abre" required>
```

Para uma largura de 200px com **tamanho das letras 36 px** coloquei um padding-left de 50 px.

```
.menor{
   padding-left:45px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: 36px;
 }
```

**Os exemplos foram testados no Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, Safari e Galaxy A5**

IE input time não funciona